# SQL window using Case (Teradata)

Tags: sql, teradata, window-functions

I have a table in Teradata with clients and their trades with certain products.

| Client | Product | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | P1 | 1.1.2020 |
| C1 | P1 | 31.1.2020 |
| C1 | P2 | 1.2.2020 |
| C1 | P3 | 1.3.2020 |
| C2 | P2 | 1.4.2020 |
| C2 | P2 | 1.5.2020 |

I need a select that will return one row per client with last trade date accross all products and last trade date for a selected product, e.g. P1. In case there is no sale of P1, it shows null.

| Client | LastP | LastP1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| C1 | 1.3.2020 | 31.1.2020 |
| C2 | 1.5.2020 | null |

I can get the values separately but how do I receive one row per client?

```
SELECT
Max (Date) Over (PARTITION BY Client) AS LastP,
CASE WHEN Product='P1'
 THEN Max (Date) Over (PARTITION BY Client, Product)
ELSE NULL END AS LastP1
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must move the `CASE` expression inside `MAX()` window function and partition by client only:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Client,
       MAX(Date) Over (PARTITION BY Client) AS LastP,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Product='P1' THEN Date END) Over (PARTITION BY Client) AS LastP1
FROM tablename
```

Or simpler:

```
SELECT Client,
       MAX(Date) AS LastP,
       MAX(CASE WHEN Product='P1' THEN Date END) AS LastP1
FROM tablename
GROUP BY Client
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=137b17792fc7accbfe7380924a51d40a).

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was looking for. I was trying moch more complicated solutions :-) Now, it is easy and obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
 WITH YOUR_TABLE_SAMPLE(CLIENT,PRODUCT,DATE) AS
(
   SELECT 'C1' ,    'P1', CAST('20200101'AS DATE) UNION ALL
   SELECT 'C1',     'P1' ,  CAST('20200131' AS DATE)UNION ALL
   SELECT'C1' , 'P2' ,  CAST('20200201' AS DATE)UNION ALL
   SELECT'C1' , 'P3' ,  CAST('20200301'AS DATE)UNION ALL
   SELECT'C2' , 'P2' ,  CAST('20200401'AS DATE)UNION ALL
   SELECT'C2' , 'P2' ,  CAST('20200501'AS DATE)
)
SELECT  C.CLIENT,MAX(C.DATE)LAST_TRADE_DATE,
 MAX(
      CASE WHEN C.PRODUCT='P1'THEN C.DATE
      ELSE NULL
      END
   )AS LAST_P1_TRADE_DATE
 FROM YOUR_TABLE_SAMPLE AS C
 GROUP BY C.CLIENT
```